How can I prepare my recycled wood table for outdoor use?
I have a wooden table designed for indoor use that I'd love to place on my patio. However, I'm not very knowledgeable about this process and could use some advice.
The table I have is ZAK (from Structube). From the manufacturer's website, I know that the wood is 100% recycled teak wood, and the table surface has an intricate geometric pattern stained with tea leaves.
From what I've gathered online, the general recommendation is to sand the table down and apply wood sealer. However, I really like the table's current finish, and I'm concerned that sanding might damage the pattern on tabletop.
Here are my questions:

Will sanding damage the design on the table? Is it absolutely necessary, or can I skip this step?
Is it absolutely necessary to sand the table before applying the wood sealer? or can I apply directly to the table, skipping the step?
What type of weather-resistant paint would you recommend? I was thinking about Thompson's WaterSeal Waterproofer Plus Exterior Tinted Wood Protector Transparent? Or should I buy a Teak Sealer?
The table has metal legs. What kind of painting can I use for them?


This is a duplicate of your question a few weeks ago.   Indoor stuff does not last as long outside, even with sealers/paints.  Unless you make sure the sealer/paint is always in good condition.  If any MDF/similar is used as a base, it does not like moisture at all.  It turns into mush fast.

Real teak is good outside but expensive.  Recycle teak on a cheap base is not good.

Hello! I deleted my previous question because it was missing some key information.
I understand recycled teak might be less reliable than true teak. But I have another table for indoor use now, so I have to put this one on the patio.
Do you have any suggestion for making this a decent outdoor table? Maybe applying the sealer more often (like once every 6 months? 1 year ? 2 years? )? Is it better wood or teak sealant? Or are they the same?

They might be different, but it is the wood under the teak that will need good sealing.  If it is MDF/particle board as a base, then any moisture in contact will ruin it, even just dew/fog.  Being an indoor table, it is a very good chance it is MDF.

The table is manufactured to be used indoors.  If it was meant to be used outdoors, it would be labeled  "for outdoor or indoor use" .   Trying to change that by modifying usually has undesired results that is known as "creating trash."  Enjoy your tabel indoors. It sound to be lovely.  Perhaps look to re-create a new table for outside using outdoor suitable materials.

I’m speculating about the nature of the top, so ymmv.
On one hand, it might be a particle board or mdf base that has teak veneer applied to it. In this case, I’d suggest you save yourself heartache and just sell/donate the table instead of taking it outdoors and watching it rot.
If it’s actually solid teak (and it might be, given the design… a particularly good clue would be to see if the underside matches the top), then you might have success. I’d separate the top from the legs and apply at least 3 coats of exterior spar varnish (oil based) on every surface. The goal is to encapsulate it, as the glue may or may not be moisture resistant. Legs would get an exterior enamel (multiple coats) from a spray can.
Regular maintenance will be important. Reapply finishes annually.

Personally, I would strongly suggest finding a new home for that table (Freecycle, Craigslist, Habitat Re/Stores, etc.) rather than trying to abuse it and risking destroying it. Buy, or build, real outdoor furniture for outdoor use.
